# Image processing general questions and terms

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

) In digital image processing, an image is a matrix of rows (m) and columns (n) denoted by [m,n]. When showing as an image output would the rows become the Y axis and and column the X axis? Just wanted to confirm this as sometime it is confusing. In Matlab and in textbook what is the convention?

2. Do we call a gray-scale image as a matrix or a 2D array? What is the difference between these two?
3. What is a tensor image?

Comment: you can easily google the first one. The second one is yes, a 2D array is a matrix. A tensor image is an image that has multiple values per pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• The rows would extend from left-to-right. The columns would extend from top-to-bottom. Below each square represents a pixel within the image. To count the number of rows you would go along the y-axis to get dimension (m). To count the number of columns you would go along the x-axis to get dimension (n).

In the below "Test Image" m = 2 and n = 4.

[image: Image Test]

[image: Image Conventions]

• As the comment above stated a 2D-array is a matrix. A greyscale image only has a single channel causing it to be a 2D-array. An RGB-image can have 3 channels leading to a matrix with the third dimension of 3.

[image: RGB Image/Multi-Channel Image]

• A tensor image provides more than one data sample per pixel. A tensor image is a multi-dimensional array. I can imagine various types that may take advantage of RGB, HSV, LUV colour spaces along with other more sophisticated data.

### Here is an example that might shed some light:

[image: Image Properties]

```
Image = imread("Image.png");
%Grabbing the size of the image%
[m,n,h] = size(Image); 

Number_Of_Rows = m;
Number_Of_Columns = n;
Number_Of_Colour_Channels = h;

fprintf("Number of rows (m): %d pixels\n",Number_Of_Rows);
fprintf("Number of columns (n): %d pixels\n",Number_Of_Columns);
fprintf("Number of colour channels: %d channels\n",Number_Of_Colour_Channels);

%Plotting the image%
Figure = figure(1);
imshow(Image);
truesize(Figure);

title('RGB Image');
xlabel(["Number of Columns" num2str(Number_Of_Columns)]);
ylabel(["Number of Rows" num2str(Number_Of_Rows)]);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. In the image the row, `m` is represented by the Y axis and column, `n` by X axis. But in the explanation you mentioned that rows `m` extends from left to right --> this to me means traversing the Y axis OR did you do a typo where the rows means top to bottom? Is the horizontal & vertical axis reversed? I mean, the X and Y axis in the explanation and the picture do not match Can you please clarify?

Comment: I added a diagram to clarify.  Hopefully, this clears up any misconceptions. Image processing best described with images right.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. So just to confirm if I understood you correctly, (1) rows --> correspond to Y axis and columns -->X axis? (2) Why in textbooks (http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/toolbox/images/intro28.html) it is mentioned that the coordinate is reversed? What is the reversal coordinate or is it the one that you have explained in your answer? In maths, we write x c-oordinate first followed by y coordinate (x,y) so `x` means accessing the horizontal axis and `y` means `vertical axis`. In image, it seems reversed?

Comment: So if I want to access element at (2,3) coordinate position, I should go to row 2 and column 3 in image, similar to the access scheme in Maths array ?

Comment: Yes, accessing element (2,3) will give you the element in row 2 and column 3.

Comment: But in graph, the first element 2 represents the x axis and second element = 3 represents the y axis. But in image, this is reversed to me. Or did I misunderstand.

Comment: Oh, I see the conventions you are going by in the article. If I have this right  if (x = 2, y = 3) → (row = 3, column = 2). In MATLAB you would call this by using Image(3,2).

Comment: Yes, this is my confusion which one is correct? Translating the image to a graph shows that the coordinates are reversed. But your answer makes more sense. In general, if x is the horizontal axis and y is the vertical axis then in an image representation x = columns and y = rows like you shows with the tiger image?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In academia, it is common to denote in the (x,y) format. This causes the convention to be reversed. Typically I work in rows (m) and columns (n) to avoid any confusion since most programming languages abide by this. I'll create a small script that you can play with to experiment.

Comment: I see, so the (x,y) in images does not mean that the first element refers to the horizontal axis (rows) and the second element in y is the y axis (colm)?  thank you for the script and explanation

Comment: Here's the script I came up with to clarify. It uses a small grid and set of pixels that you can play with to test around. https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Sample_Image_Test

Comment: Yeah, it, unfortunately, doesn't. Not sure why the conventions are like that. It even states in the article/textbook that was linked.